# O que significa o comando: gfortran -c -03 $<

Tags: makefile, fortran

Galera, eu estou tentando entender um programa aqui que eu estou usando na minha iniciação científica, mas to com uma dúvida em uma make file.

```
# makefile for code
OBJ1 = main.o derivs.o filter.o

code: $(OBJ1)
    gfortran $(OBJ1) -o prg

.f.o:
    gfortran -c -O3 $<

clean:
    rm *~ *.o *.dat prg
```

Os "code:", ".f.o" e "clean:" são os comandos que eu tenho que utilizar com o make pra poder executar a linha que está logo abaixo deles, pelo que eu entendi.
O que significa essa linha? 
gfortran -c -O3 $<

Ahh, e só pra ver se eu tô entendendo certo, o -o é pra compilar o código pra um arquivo, já o -c faz isso também, mas é usado pra quando a gente tem que juntar um ou mais códigos que estão em arquivos diferentes, é isso?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Eu não gosto muito da sintaxe `.f.o` no Makefile. Prefiro usar `%.o : %.f`, que significa _o alvo terminado em `.o` depende de um arquivo terminado em `.f` que tenha o mesmo radical_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, esse é um `Makefile`. Para maiores detalhes, o pessoal da GNU disponibiliza um manual online: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Por partes:

1. você está usando uma sintaxe de [regras implícitas](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules)
2. está dito que qualquer arquivo Fortan (`.f`) vai ser transformando num arquivo objeto de mesma raiz (`.o`)
3. `gfortran -c -O3 $<` é uma linha de comando:

   - `gfortran` é o nome do comando a ser executado
   - `-c` indica que é uma compilação parcial (a saída será um arquivo objeto `.o`)
   - `-O3` é a flag de compilação que indica o [nível de otimização 3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)
   - `$<` é uma [variável automática](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) do `Makefile`; seu valor é o nome da primeira dependência do target chamado, no caso pode ser `main.f` (target `main.o`), `derivs.f` (target `derivs.o`) ou `filter.f` (target `filter.o`)

#### EDIT

Note que a opção `-o` é distinta da opção `-O`. `-o` (minúsculo) indica arquivo de saída no GCC, e `-O` é o nível de otimização.